# Handling extra observable when using RxJava with retrofit

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I am using RxAndroid and as a result of two observables I want to execute a retrofit request. So I am using zip operator

```
Observable<RequestBuilder> obs = a.zipWith(b, (lhs, rhs) -> builder.b(rhs).a(lhs));
```

Now the problem here is that builder.build() return another observable **ObservableRequest** but this method now makes it **ObservableObservableRequest** which I cant seem to figure out. I have already done this, but I want to do it correctly...

```
obs.map(
(builder) -> builder.build(api)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(this::setData)
);
```

Perhaps something like

```
    obs.map((builder) -> builder.build(api))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(this::setData);
```

Answer (score 1):

DeBuGGeR, This may help.

`login` method in `RestPresenter` class

```
public void login(String email, String password) {
        mRestService.getApi()
                .postAuth(email, password, "") //create Observable
                .timeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //time out
                .retry(RETRY_COUNT_FOR_REQUEST) //times to retry
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<AuthBean>() { // your model
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        // do nothing
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        mView.showError("Error");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(AuthBean posts) {
                        mView.workWithLoginResponse(posts);
                    }
                });
}
```

Call it in your `activity`

```
RestService mRestService = new RestService();
mRestPresenter = new RestPresenter(YourActivity.this, mRestService);
mRestPresenter.login(email, password);
```

`RestService` class may look like this

```
public class RestService {
    private ProviderApi mProviderApi;
    private long CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 15L;
    private long READ_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS       = 15L;
    private long WRITE_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS      = 25L;

    public RestService() {
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
        };
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.URL_SERVER)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(getClient())) // need square/okhttp
                .build();
        mProviderApi = restAdapter.create(ProviderApi.class);
    }

    private OkHttpClient getClient() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        client.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        client.setWriteTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        return client;
    }

    public ProviderApi getApi() {
        return mProviderApi;
    }
}
```

`mView` is your `activity`, so you just create `workWithLoginResponse` method and do what you want with server answer.

Also `ProviderApi` is interface and may contains something like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/auth")
Observable<AuthBean>
postAuth(@Field("login") String login,
         @Field("password") String password);
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir! But this is irrelevant, i just want to know how to convert Observable of Observable of Response to Observable of Response. Please take a look at my brackets.

Comment: @DeBuGGeR, indicate in your code what Observable you want to receive and you get it. you also may change `AuthBean` in code above to your own response model.

Comment: i have already metioned it. ObservableObservableRequest is being returned but I want ObservableRequest to be returned

Comment: @DeBuGGeR, i mean, indicate in your code what you want to receive. could you provide more code?

Comment: @VladimirMarkeev can you post link to your sample project (github maybe?) or can you please also post the "ProviderApi" class as well?

Answer (score 0):

> ObservableObservableRequest is being returned but I want
>   ObservableRequest to be returned

How about `flatMap`?

```
//create Observable<Observable<Integer>>
Observable.just(Observable.just(1, 2, 3))
        //convert to Observable<Integer>
        .flatMap(integerObservable -> integerObservable)
        //receive Integer values
        .subscribe(integer -> {
            //do something with Integer
        });
```

[More about `flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)